# Copied Angular 7 Project does not compile

Tags: angular, npm, angular7

I have made an angular 7 project from scratch and I wanted to save it at a certain point (I'm not into versioning systems like git yet) so I manually copied the whole project folder and then tried to start that project with **ng serve** which gave me the following error:

> "ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(7,34): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module './main-nav/main-nav.component'."

Angular 7 compilation error:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea how this happens and why it happens....
**how can a manual copy of a project that compiles fine "loose" files during copy/paste------> that doesn't make sense**
when i start the original project as usual with ng serve everything works fine.
so can anyone give me a hint how i can save a properly reproducible version of
the project anywhere?

**Edit1**: manually erasing node_modules folder and reinstalling via npm installing produces the same error :

[image]

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to remove the spaces within the import string.

`import { MainNavComponent } from "./main-nav/main-nav.component";`

OR...

You may need to change the path all together. What's your folder structure look like?

Comment: thanks for your answer ! folder structure is the standard one created with ng new... how do you save your projects when you have stable builds?

Comment: Is this the right answer? If so, please mark accordingly.

Comment: no it is not...it doesnt solve the problem and it does not explain why this happens...but thanks for your help man !

Comment: I don't know what the default folder structure is. I would recommend posting your folder structure and the app.module.ts code.

Comment: added pic with structure(s)

Comment: @MaximilianSchulz I'm looking at the pic and I'm confused because your code doesn't have spaces but the output says you have spaces. So maybe you're trolling? And if you're not, I would figure out if your computer or ide is adding spaces for some reason. It's hard to diagnose when the information provided makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The complete project folder must be pretty big because all the modules. Not a good idea to handle it that way.

An Angular project is fit for git at the very beginning. It comes with a gitignore to skip all the files that are not directly connected to your code. So have a look at it.

If I copy the complete folder then I can rebuild it without problem. Maybe you just saved src and not the big folder for the modules.

Try

```
npm install
```

to regenerate it.

**EDIT** Just saw your picture. Do not think its the missing modules.

Comment: Wouldn't this problem create a different error message?

Comment: hi guys totally thanks for helping out....tried your suggestions but still the same....

Answer (score 0):

Only a workaround, I still dont know why the error occurs but here's what can be done:

-delete main-nav component manually in **app.module.ts** and **app.component.html**

-then reinstall navbar with *ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=main**2**-nav*

-notice the different naming parameter! When re-installing the component with different name, the angular compiler does not complain!

Of course you also have to manually re-apply styles etc. to the component...